# In Firebase, how can I determine whether a user has write access to a node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

...without actually saving data to that node?

For example, I have a chat app. I'd like to check whether a user has write access to a node *before* showing the "Send message" button.

Answer (score 2):

Define another node with the exact same set of security rules, that exists for no reason other than to perform these checks, and attempt a write there first to see if it finishes without error.

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is to replicate a similar, simplified version of the rules in your application code. You'd typically only replicate the benign checks, and leave extra validations against malicious users solely on the server.

Although I must admit Doug's version also sounds interesting. :-)